# Identifying an exact expression for a decimal value

Tags: reference-request, decimal-expansion

I'm looking for a website or something like that which helps me find the exact value of a decimal value of a number. Of course, we cannot determine the exact value from a decimal as it is finite, but for example if I type in $1.414...$, it should me all probable forms which I am looking for, one would simply be it's rational form, one could be $\sqrt{2}$ and many others... and we can get our exact form by typing in more digits. I believe such a thing would be possible because I have seen something like that in past, but now I have forgotten what was it. Another example would be if I type $1.155727349...$, it shows me $\dfrac{\pi}{e}$.

---

More simply put, is there any way in which I can get to the exact value of a number from it's decimal value if I know which constants would be appearing in it?

Thank you!

Comment: I tried WolframaAlpha and it works! However, if there are any other sites/software specifically designed for this purpose, I'd certainly like to know.

Comment: There's the original Inverse Symbolic Calculator: http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/projects/ISC/ISCmain.html It's ok, but not fantastic. There *was* a better one, but it's offline. :(  But just in case it comes back, here's its URL: https://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes! I was talking about this only... I saw it before, but forgot about it. Thank you!

Comment: If you can use Python, the 3rd party library mpmath has a function for identifying numbers, which may be helpful: https://mpmath.org/doc/current/identification.html You can play with it on the SageMathCell server ; here's a tiny [demo](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwtyzsOAjEMBNA-pxiJJhHS8pG2pOIInCCwXuHCieOYgtvjgm5mnma3LhCV6m-waDePlg54kEONXjy5tyS6bDpxw3pOgXej6oSK9pEnWRoh-YJjXJc5zPNaCk64JjVunkf5h2DeqDnv3xjLD8MjJxc=&lang=python). It's not very smart, but it's better than nothing, I guess. ;)

Comment: Strictly speaking, we can never know which expression matches since the next digits could be different. But there are symbolic calculators finding possible matches (Wolfram Alpha is one of the tools). Of course, the more digits are given , the more likely is that the match is actually the intented number.

Comment: Also note that none of the tools will find every imaginable combination of known irrational numbers. But expressions you have in mind should be found without difficulty.